# grails application design for multiple checkbox scenario

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a Domain lookup table of Ethnicities.  A person can have multiple ethnicities - caucasian, indian, latino, etc.  There are around 10 total.

In one part of my application a user will select their own ethnicity, so they will check one or more of the checkboxes.  In another part of the application a different type of user can specify to be matched with someone by ethnicity.  This user can also specify one ore more, but the can also specify 'no preference'.

So the first user would see:
caucasian
latino
asian
indian
...

The second user sees:
No preference
caucasian
latino
asian
indian

My question is how to implement this in the lookup table/domain user object.  The 'no preference' is throwing me off.  Is it a boolean in the user object, or another value in the ethnicity lookup table that gets filtered out when the view for first user is displayed?

There is also the option of having the no preference triggering a check all by jquery behind the scenes so that second user would have every ethnicity as part of their their domain object.  But then I have to do kludgy stuff like 'does the second user have every ethnicity stored in their domain, if yes then check 'no preference' in the view'.

EDIT:

It's probably better to show the UI.  This is what I need to implement.  The ethnicities are stored in a look up table.  My domain will look something like this:

```
class Profile P
   static hasMany = [ethnicity:Ethnicity]
...
}
```

[image]

And here is what the other use will see:

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just have no preference be represented by a null value? You should include some actual domains with specific questions. It is hard to determine what you are getting at.

Comment: Ok I posted the UI and some code from the Domain object, which is not complete since I'm not sure how to implement it yet.

Comment: I would store the Any as a `Boolean` on `Profile`. Something like `"noEthnicityPreference"` that you would set to true if they check the box. In that case I wouldnt populate anything in the `hasMany` relationship.

Comment: I ended up going with the boolean field to represent the 'any' variable.  It's worked out well.

Answer (score 0):

if ANY == [caucasian, latino, asian, indian......] then additional property is not required.(if user select ANY, you add all ethnicities) 
ELSE you can use a list [ANY, caucasian, latino, asian, indian...]. although  'ANY' is not ethnicity.